# Reference value of expression inside list comprehension in Python?

Tags: python, list-comprehension, temporary, temporaries

If I have a list comprehension like

```
[mymap.get(x, None) for x in oldlist if mymap.get(x,None)]
```

Is there a way to do `mymap.get(x,None)` only *once* here?

I imagine something like

```
[y for x in oldlist if mymap.get(x,None) as y]
```

but currently this is a `SyntaxError` in py 2.x. I would like to be able to reference the resulting values of either the ["expression"](http://docs.python.org/2/reference/expressions.html#list-displays) of list comprehension or from the "list_if" part of it.

I've also tried

```
[_ for x in oldlist if mymap.get(x,None)]
```

but that's a `NameError`, I guess `_` being only some interpreter feature on lines.

**edit**

Is there a way to reference this temporary/anonymous/unnamed variable somehow, without re-iterating the list?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
[y for y in (mymap.get(x, None) for x in oldlist) if y]
```

Comment: won't this re-iterate through the list?

Comment: @naxa no it won't, that's the point of it, it's a generator expression (notice `()` brackets instead `[]`)

Answer (score 2):

```
filter(None, (mymap.get(x, None) for x in oldlist))
```

or if it suits your fancy the *equivalent* code using `bool` instead

```
filter(bool, (mymap.get(x, None) for x in oldlist))
```

And to answer your question, there's no way to reference the [output function](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_comprehension#Overview) from the [predicate](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_comprehension#Overview).